# Attempted deep frying smoke fiasco

Tags: deep-frying, dutch-oven

I recently tried deep frying some chicken and it went horribly wrong. The oil started to smoke so much that I had to step outside because it was so thick. Even after I brought the Dutch oven I was using outside it smoked for a long while after. My question is why was it smoking so much.

The oil was cooking in a 9 inch cast iron Dutch oven. I had the heat on about a 9 (out of 10). The oil was peanut oil. At one point I put the lid on the cast iron. It was after I took it off that it began to smoke. I should have been more careful about how I researched the safety of doing this sort of cooking. Can anyone explain why this happened?

Comment: Lot of background, but missing one essential piece of information… what was the oil? Oils have 'smoke points' - temperatures which can vary wildly depending on what the oil is. Also, your heat… 9 out of 10 is a bit vague, was this a stove-top, gas oven??

Comment: I added that it was peanut oil. Yeah I didn't have a thermometer but I recognize the danger now of not using one.

Comment: Was it refined peanut oil? How were you heating it?

Answer (score 6):

When deep frying, the most important piece of equipment you can have is a decent thermometer--many candy/frying thermometers have a clip that can be positioned on the edge of a dutch oven so that you can keep watch of the temperature while frying (like [this one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v5h7b.png)).

Different oils have different [smoke points](https://anovaculinary.com/the-anova-overview-to-cooking-oils-smoke-points/). For refined peanut oil, the smoke point is 450°F / 232°C. It sounds like you got your oil too hot, and it reached the smoke point. **This can be very dangerous.** Just above the smoke point is when oil can actually ignite, causing a serious fire risk.

Generally, you would want to fry well below the smoke point temperature. Recipes generally will recommend frying temperatures of 300°F / 150°C to 375°F to 190°C, depending on what you're frying.

Trying to regulate heat simply by using the knob/setting on your stovetop is not a reliable way to maintain heat when deep frying. Using a thermometer will help ensure you are able to keep oil in the desired range.